# Почему текст выровнялся по вертикали? Как исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вот такая вот ситуация. Полагаю, это связано с расположением блоков после `display: inline-block;`, но никак не могу исправить...

```css
/* Font style */

* {
  font-family: "Arial";
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Info block style */

.info {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.info p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Bar style */

.bar {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.tab:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}


/* Data style */

.data {
  display: none;
}

.enabled {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*    width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(700px - 140px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.enabled p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="info">
        <ul class="bar">
            <li><a href="" class="tab">First tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tab">Second tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tab">Third tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tab">Fourth tab</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="data">
            <p>
             Text No. 1
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="data">
            <p>
             Text No. 2
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="data">
            <p>
             Text No. 3
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="data enabled">
            <p>
            The City Council of Helsinki (Finnish: Helsingin kaupunginvaltuusto, Swedish: Helsingfors stadsfullmäktige) is the main decision-making organ in the local politics of Helsinki, Finland.[1] The City Council deals with issues such as city planning, schools, health care, and public transport.
            </p>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .enabled {vertical-align: top;} - если то о чем, я думаю.

Comment: @Kjuri Вот действительно. Это сработало. Единственное, что меня смущает: разве `vertical-align` по умолчанию не `top`?

Comment: @Kjuri Всегда вроде текст прилипает к верху родительского блока, а тут вдруг выравнялся по середине без явного на то указания. Странно..

Comment: действительно что то странное...не вижу в коде изменения `vertical-align`... по умолчание не `top`, a `baseline` - `Выравнивает базовую линию текущего элемента по базовой линии родителя. Если родительский элемент не имеет базовой линии, то за нее принимается нижняя граница элемента.`

Comment: так и есть, выравнивается baseline, а не по центру, как кажется в коде примера. Чтобы это увидеть - уменьшите количество текста блока enabled. Тогда лучше видно, что он выровнен по низу(baseline) меню.

Comment: @Kjuri Как же рассчитывается тогда baseline? В сети ничего по этому найти не могу. Я думал, что текст уйдёт в самый низ блока, как вы говорили, а получилось [это](https://thecum.zone/db88ad455c.png). Как это работает?

Comment: baseline, это не самый низ указанной высоты, а как бы низ текста. https://assets.htmlacademy.ru/content/blog/94/group-1@1x.png

Comment: baseline - это базовая линия шрифта (низ строчных букв без учета хвостиков). Как именно выровняется элемент, соответственно, зависит от используемого в нем шрифта.  Вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ3tg.png